# Using jquery functions on an opened window

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, node.js, window

I don't know if this is a simple or complex question (or if it's been asked before). I'm trying to open a webpage in my browser, say google.com, and then use jquery to grab/modify those elements. Here is my code below:

```
$scope.populateUrl = function () {

    var openWindow = function () {
        return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
            resolve(window.open('https://www.google.com'))
        })
    }

    openWindow().then(function (wnd) {
        console.log(wnd.document)
        var inputs = wnd.document.getElementsByTagName('input')
        console.log(inputs)
    })
}
```

I feel like this should be a really simple problem but when I console log wnd.document I get:

```
#document
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
  </html>
```

And the inputs variable is empty. Shouldn't wnd.document be the html for google? If it makes a difference I'm using Node for this project.

Comment: You need to wait for the page to load. Plus I dont know if you'll be able to interact as they are different domains.  Not sure haven't tried in ages.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do by wrapping it in a $q promise. I was wondering how $q would know when the other window is finished loading and I couldn't really think of an answer. Is there a way to get $q to wait for the other window?

Comment: I know I've done this with an `iframe` before. Not sure if that helps, but just a heads up.

Comment: probably have to get the promise to resolve your self but should be able to do something like wnd.document.onload = function(){ var inputs = wnd.document.getElementsByTagName('input')}

Comment: tried timeout to get a refence to document after it was loaded but got blocked because of cors

Comment: your resolve is wrong, should resolve in the onload event of new window.

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand from `$scope` you are writing angularjs in client side.

You are trying to get google.com from your site with your user's cookies. So why not getting paypal.com after and see what your user's balance is or make some transfers? As you understand if that was possible it will cause huge security problems.

Anyway what you are trying to do is impossible.

You could try to send a get request to the site you want and if this site allows it through access controll allow origin you could get the response you want.

Although if you are just want to scrappe a site and get some data from it you should do it server side. There are several modules to do that like: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio
or a whole program made specific for that:http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html